# How to create imapala table with complex data type and how I can specify delimiter for array type column

Tags: impala

I am trying to create **impala table** with **array** column type, I have to use custom delimiter for array type column.

I tried below query. But, its throwing error.

```
Create table array_demo( arra_col ARRAY<string>) row format delimited fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|' stored as parquet
```

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the `ROW FORMAT` clause and the subclauses specifying the terminators, and include a `STORED AS` clause (Parquet is the only format Impala supports with complex data).

The data files to load the table have to be in parquet format too.

If you don't have the data file in Parquet format, you can create the table in Hive, 
then create a copy using `CREATE TABLE … AS SELECT` (CTAS statement), with `STORED AS PARQUET`.

You then can query the table in Impala.

As an example

```sql
-- Create table in Hive
CREATE TABLE array_demo( arra_col ARRAY<STRING>) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

-- Copy the table as parquet format
CREATE TABLE array_demo_impala AS 
SELECT *
FROM array_demo
STORED AS PARQUET;
```